# New coordinates when reshaping a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Take a 4-D matrix `A` with `s1=size(A,1)`, `s2=size(A,2)`, `s3=size(A,3)`, `s4=size(A,4)`.

Consider

```
 B=reshape(A, s1*s2*s3*s4,1)
```

For example,

```
  s1=2;
  s2=3;
  s3=2;
  s4=4;
  A(:,:,1,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
  A(:,:,1,2)=[7 8 9; 10 11 12];
  A(:,:,1,3)=[13 14 15; 16 17 18];
  A(:,:,1,4)=[19 20 21; 22 23 24];
  A(:,:,2,1)=[25 26 27; 28 29 30];
  A(:,:,2,2)=[31 32 33; 34 35 36];
  A(:,:,2,3)=[37 38 39; 40 41 42];
  A(:,:,2,4)=[43 44 45; 46 47 48];
  B=reshape(A, s1*s2*s3*s4,1);
  %B=[1;4;2;5;3;6;25;28;26;29;27;30;7;10;8;11;9;12;...];
```

Given coordinates `(i,j,h,k)`, I would like your help to write a function that gives me the position of `A(i,j,h,k)` in `B`.

I know how to do that when `A` is a 3-D matrix. In that case,

```
position_in_B= i + ( j-1 + (h-1)*s2 ) * s1;
```

How can I extend this result to 4-D matrices?

Comment: why not use ind2sub?

Comment: I tried this but does not work: `i=1;` `j=1;` `h=1;` `k=1;` `ind = [i j h k];`
`sz = [s1 s2 s3 s4];`
`position_in_B = ind2sub(sz,ind);`

Comment: Actually `ind2sub` seems to go from `B` to `A`. Here I want the other way around.

Comment: `position_in_B = sub2ind(size(A), i,j,h,k)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can use `sub2ind` ,  for example:

```
B(sub2ind(size(A),1,1,1,4))
```

or you can continue with the extension you wrote:

```
position_in_B= @(i,j,h,k) i + ( j-1 + ( h-1 + (k-1) *s3 ) *s2 ) * s1;

B(position_in_B(1,1,1,4))
```